# Granting permissions to Python file in Azure Web Services

Tags: php, python, bash, azure, permissions

I am hosting a **PHP/MySQL** application on Microsoft Azure App Services. There is a section of the PHP that calls for the execution of a python file. Code looks as so:

```
exec("python3 /site/wwwroot/dataProcess.py");
```

It is not running for some reason. But not giving me back errors. I was wondering if it's because the permissions to do everything have not been yet granted to the file.

My app is running on a linux server

OR

I was wondering if it is because the path to python is not correct either in the PHP `exec()` command or in the shebang.

OR

Could it be an issue with the python modules I'm using in the .py file. But I am pretty sure those modules are included in all versions of python 3.

I have tried making sure my db credentials are all good. I have tried changing the python3 to just python.

```
exec("python3 /site/wwwroot/dataProcess.py");
```

//or

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import csv
import MySQLdb
from datetime import datetime
```

In the end this python file should be querying in some info from my db, inserting new data, and exporting a csv file to a folder in my application's directory

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues for you if your app would like to be running on Azure WebApp on Linux.

1. If you followed the offical tutorial `Create a PHP app in App Service on Linux` to create a PHP app via the commands as below, I'm afraid there is no Python runtime on your WebApp.

   ```
   # Bash
   az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name <app-name> --runtime "PHP|7.0" --deployment-local-git
   # PowerShell
   az --% webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name <app-name> --runtime "PHP|7.0" --deployment-local-git
   ```
2. So you can follow the offical documents [`Configure a Linux PHP app for Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-php) or [`Configure a Linux Python app for Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python) to check your runtime in Cloud Shell, to make sure the required runtimes are ready for your app.

   ```
   az webapp config show --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --query linuxFxVersion
   ```
3. If you want to get the result or error information of PHP `exec` function, you need to  change your code as below to display the necessary message, please refer to the PHP offical reference for [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function.

   ```
   <?php
      echo exec("python3 /site/wwwroot/dataProcess.py");
   ?>
   ```

So after inspect your app on Azure WebApp on Linux, the solution is to build a custom Docker image for pre-installing all runtimes and packages required by your app, then to deploy it. Please refer to the offical tutorial [`Tutorial: Build a custom image and run in App Service from a private registry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image).

Hope it helps.